# WebAuthn: Is it possible to get public key from credentials.get

Tags: webauthn, fido, passkey

When we send request for `credential.create` we get back `attestationObject` which contains PublicKey within CBOR format, but when we call `credential.get` we have only `authenticatorData` without PublicKey data. So is it possible to retrieve PublicKey from Passkey, after `credential.create` call?

The issue is when we created a Passkey we can have connectivity problem so the PublicKey store request to backend will fail, but passkey itself is already created and we can't check the signature without PublicKey next time user want to SignIn!

`credential.create` request

```
{
  "challenge": "nhkQXfE59Jb97VyyNJkvDiXucMEvltduvcrDmGrODHY",
  "rp": {
    "name": "CredMan App Test",
    "id": "credential-manager-app-test.glitch.me"
  },
  "user": {
    "id": "2HzoHm_hY0CjuEESY9tY6-3SdjmNHOoNqaPDcZGzsr0",
    "name": "helloandroid@gmail.com",
    "displayName": "helloandroid@gmail.com"
  },
  "pubKeyCredParams": [
    {
      "type": "public-key",
      "alg": -7
    },
    {
      "type": "public-key",
      "alg": -257
    }
  ],
  "timeout": 1800000,
  "attestation": "none",
  "excludeCredentials": [],
  "authenticatorSelection": {
    "authenticatorAttachment": "platform",
    "requireResidentKey": true,
    "residentKey": "required",
    "userVerification": "required"
  }
}
```

`credential.create` response

```
{
  "id": "KEDetxZcUfinhVi6Za5nZQ",
  "type": "public-key",
  "rawId": "KEDetxZcUfinhVi6Za5nZQ",
  "response": {
    "clientDataJSON": "eyJ0eXBlIjoid2ViYXV0aG4uY3JlYXRlIiwiY2hhbGxlbmdlIjoibmhrUVhmRTU5SmI5N1Z5eU5Ka3ZEaVh1Y01Fdmx0ZHV2Y3JEbUdyT0RIWSIsIm9yaWdpbiI6ImFuZHJvaWQ6YXBrLWtleS1oYXNoOk1MTHpEdll4UTRFS1R3QzZVNlpWVnJGUXRIOEdjVi0xZDQ0NEZLOUh2YUkiLCJhbmRyb2lkUGFja2FnZU5hbWUiOiJjb20uZ29vZ2xlLmNyZWRlbnRpYWxtYW5hZ2VyLnNhbXBsZSJ9",
    "attestationObject": "o2NmbXRkbm9uZWdhdHRTdG10oGhhdXRoRGF0YViUj5r_fLFhV-qdmGEwiukwD5E_5ama9g0hzXgN8thcFGRdAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEChA3rcWXFH4p4VYumWuZ2WlAQIDJiABIVgg4RqZaJyaC24Pf4tT-8ONIZ5_Elddf3dNotGOx81jj3siWCAWXS6Lz70hvC2g8hwoLllOwlsbYatNkO2uYFO-eJID6A"
  }
}
```

`credential.get` request

```
{
  "challenge": "T1xCsnxM2DNL2KdK5CLa6fMhD7OBqho6syzInk_n-Uo",
  "allowCredentials": [],
  "timeout": 1800000,
  "userVerification": "required",
  "rpId": "credential-manager-app-test.glitch.me"
}
```

`credential.get` response

```
{ 
  "id": "KEDetxZcUfinhVi6Za5nZQ",
  "type": "public-key",
  "rawId": "KEDetxZcUfinhVi6Za5nZQ",
  "response": {
    "clientDataJSON": "eyJ0eXBlIjoid2ViYXV0aG4uZ2V0IiwiY2hhbGxlbmdlIjoiVDF4Q3NueE0yRE5MMktkSzVDTGE2Zk1oRDdPQnFobzZzeXpJbmtfbi1VbyIsIm9yaWdpbiI6ImFuZHJvaWQ6YXBrLWtleS1oYXNoOk1MTHpEdll4UTRFS1R3QzZVNlpWVnJGUXRIOEdjVi0xZDQ0NEZLOUh2YUkiLCJhbmRyb2lkUGFja2FnZU5hbWUiOiJjb20uZ29vZ2xlLmNyZWRlbnRpYWxtYW5hZ2VyLnNhbXBsZSJ9",
    "authenticatorData": "j5r_fLFhV-qdmGEwiukwD5E_5ama9g0hzXgN8thcFGQdAAAAAA",
    "signature": "MEUCIQCO1Cm4SA2xiG5FdKDHCJorueiS04wCsqHhiRDbbgITYAIgMKMFirgC2SSFmxrh7z9PzUqr0bK1HZ6Zn8vZVhETnyQ",
    "userHandle": "2HzoHm_hY0CjuEESY9tY6-3SdjmNHOoNqaPDcZGzsr0"
  }
}
```

Can't see anything in Webauthn doc according to that problem

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking if there is a way to get the public key on `get()` so that orphaned credentials on the authenticator but not on the server could be made to work.

Comment: @DavidWaite yes, we actually don't want to store it to server we keep pubkey on blockchain, but we need pubkey to restore wallet address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, the other answers are correct: if you missed the registration, you can't trust a random public key that is presented at assertion time!

Narrowly, however, if you're using ECDSA (which is extremely likely) then, given a signed message and a signature (both of which you have at assertion time), you can solve for the public key modulo the sign of the curve point. With two signatures from the same key, you can resolve the sign bit too.

Comment: I left some comment for the first comment, cloud you check it please? We actually do using ECDSA for signature, but I thought that it's only possible with secp256k1 curve to restore public key using signature, but passkey support only secp256r1. Will check double time, but if it's not very hard for you could you also leave the reference here?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the underlying curve is Koblitz or not. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Signature_verification_algorithm line 5. You can get (x1, y1) from r, and from guessing the sign of y1. Then multiply the line by 1/u1 and rearrange to get Q_A. (I haven't tried it, but I suspect that'll work.)

(P.s. there's a tiny chance that r will be small enough that it might have been reduced mod n. In that case you have more ambiguity that would need to be resolved with a second signature.)

Answer (score 2):

No. It is only needed on a create call and is not provided on get.

If the public key and credential ID are not tied to the account during a trusted create call (e.g. bound session), the credential should not be used.

Comment: There will be a lot situation when user had connection on passkey creation stage, but lost it on server sync stage and app can't even delete passkey on their own(within Web2).

Comment: We use passkey ECDSA secp256r1 signature for Smart Contract Wallet,(you can check EIP-4337) so actually your passkey(private key) is your wallet and you can sign transactions with it. When we got a PublicKey we can generate wallet address(there is an algorithm to turn PublicKey -> Address), so actually the wallet address and smart contract itself based on passkey PublicKey and there is no way attacker can change, because he need an access to Private key to be able to sign transactions and we consider it like an open data.

Comment: Passkey has extension system and I thought we can use it for the case

Comment: That is not really the intended use of a passkey.

Answer (score 1):

If the server is unable to save the public key for whatever reason during the registration, the server should fail the [registration ceremony](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#registration-ceremony) with an appropriate error message.  Sounds like your implementation silently fails instead.

Comment: 'should fail the registration ceremony'
But for that time Passkey already created and user can see it in the list(we use Google/Apple like a passkey provider) and as I understand we can't delete it on our own, user should go and do this on settings.

Comment: If the user can see the passkey in the list, this means your server did not fail the operation during registration, but rather allowed it to complete. You have to wait until you know for sure the credential is registered successfully before returning a success message to the client, otherwise you can get in the situation you describe. Usually this means displaying a "processing, please wait" sort of dialog.

Comment: Ok let me clarify the flow(Android/iOS):
1. Send request to Google credentials library
2. Google shows Passkey creation dialog
3. User approve creation
4. Google return all the data for Passkey(rpId, clinetJSON, attestationObject etc)
FROM THIS MOMENT if user will close the app(or lose connection) in the next time he'll see this passkey in the google's dialog
5. We save Passkey to our server

So the passkey creation flow isn't attached to our server sending flow, it's considering like created when Google returned us passkey data.